# Why is my program only printing part of what I need?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this function below that essentially will print out a schedule on a week by week basis. This is what I have so far.

```
void Date::increaseWeek()
{
    int increaseWeek = (day + 7);
    int increaseDay = (day + 1);
    int increasedDay = (day + 1);
    int increaseMonth = (month + 1);
    int increaseYear = (year + 1);
    

    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10)
    {
        if (day < 31)
        {
            std::cout << " " << month << '/' << day << '/' << year
                << " - ";

            if (increaseWeek > 31)
            {
                int subDate = increaseWeek - 32;
                day = 1 + subDate;
                std::cout << increaseMonth << '/' << day << '/' << year;
                month++;
                day++;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << month << '/' << increaseWeek << '/' << year;
                int addDay = increaseWeek + 1;
                day = addDay;
            }
        }
        else if (day == 31)
        {
            std::cout << " " << month << '/' << day << '/' << year
                << " - ";
            int subDate = increaseWeek - 32;
            day = 1 + subDate;
            std::cout << increaseMonth << '/' << day << '/' << year;
            int increaseDayAgain = day + 1;
            day = increaseDayAgain;
            month++;
        }
    }
    else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
    {
        if (day < 30)
        {
            std::cout << " " << month << '/' << day << '/' << year
                << " - ";

            if (increaseWeek > 30)
            {
                int subDate = increaseWeek - 31;
                day = 1 + subDate;
                std::cout << increaseMonth << '/' << day << '/' << year;
                month++;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << month << '/' << increaseWeek << '/' << year;
                int addDay = increaseWeek + 1;
                day = addDay;
            }
        }
        else if (day == 30)
        {
            std::cout << " " << month << '/' << day << '/' << year
                << " - ";
            int subDate = increaseWeek - 31;
            day = 1 + subDate;
            std::cout << increaseMonth << '/' << day << '/' << year;
            int increaseDayAgain = day + 1;
            day = increaseDayAgain;
            month++;
        }
    }
    else if (month == 2)
    {
        if (day < 28)
        {
            std::cout << " " << month << '/' << day << '/' << year
                << " - ";

            if (increaseWeek > 28)
            {
                int subDate = increaseWeek - 29;
                day = 1 + subDate;
                std::cout << increaseMonth << '/' << day << '/' << year;
                month++;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << month << '/' << increaseWeek << '/' << year;
                int addDay = increaseWeek + 1;
                day = addDay;
            }
        }
        else if (day == 28)
        {
            std::cout << " " << month << '/' << day << '/' << year
                << " - ";
            int subDate = increaseWeek - 29;
            day = 1 + subDate;
            month = 1;
            std::cout << increaseMonth << '/' << day << '/' << year;
            int increaseDayAgain = day + 1;
            day = increaseDayAgain;
            month++;
        
            //int addDay = rangeDay + 1;
            //day = addDay;
        }
    }
     else if (month == 12)
    {
    if (day < 31)
    {
        std::cout << " " << month << '/' << day << '/' << year
            << " - ";

        if (increaseWeek > 31)
        {
            int subDate = increaseWeek - 32;
            day = 1 + subDate;
            month = 1;
            std::cout << month << '/' << day << '/' << increaseYear;
            day++;
            year++;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << month << '/' << increaseWeek << '/' << year;
            int addDay = increaseWeek + 1;
            day = addDay;
        }
    }
    else if (day == 31)
    {
        month = 1;
        std::cout << " " << month << '/' << day << '/' << year
            << " - ";
        int subDate = increaseWeek - 32;
        day = 1 + subDate;
        std::cout << month << '/' << day << '/' << increaseYear;
        int increaseDayAgain = day + 1;
        day = increaseDayAgain;
        year++;
    }
    }
}
```

The function above seems to work until the I use it on a much larger scale. The code below is going to print a schedule for apple over the course of _____ weeks.

```
std::string fruitChoice = "Apple";
            int courseOfLife = (rand() % 350) + 349;
            int weeksOfLife = (courseOfLife / 7);

            std::cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "        SCHEDULE FOR APPLE        " << std::endl;
            std::cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << std::endl;

            printInstructionsFruit();

            Fruit appleObj = Fruit("Apple", 1, 1, 1, 1, "yes", 1, 1);
            appleObj.whenToWater();
            appleObj.light();
            appleObj.whenToFertilize();
            
            std::cout << courseOfLife;
            for (int i = 1; i <= weeksOfLife; i++) 
            {
                std::cout << "Week: " << i;
                while (i < courseOfLife)
                {
                    userdate.increaseWeek();
                    break;
                }

                std::cout << "\n----------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
            }

        }
```

This is the output that I get from running the code. The user enters a date, and a schedule is printed week by week from the first day that the user enters. However there are some problems. The week is not implemented the whole way through. The second problem is the line from above
int courseOfLife = (rand() % 350) + 349; is printing out that the courseOfLife is 390 which doesn't make sense considering the rand I have set up only allows a range of choices from 349 - 350
What I want to know is how do I make the schedule keep printing through the whole courseOfLife on a weeksOfLife Basis?

```
Week: 1 12/20/2022 - 12/27/2022
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 2 12/28/2022 - 1/4/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 3 1/5/2023 - 1/12/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 4 1/13/2023 - 1/20/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 5 1/21/2023 - 1/28/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 6 1/29/2023 - 2/5/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 7 2/6/2023 - 2/13/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 8 2/14/2023 - 2/21/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 9 2/22/2023 - 3/1/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 10 3/1/2023 - 3/8/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 11 3/9/2023 - 3/16/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 12 3/17/2023 - 3/24/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 13 3/25/2023 - 4/1/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 14 4/2/2023 - 4/9/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 15 4/10/2023 - 4/17/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 16 4/18/2023 - 4/25/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 17 4/26/2023 - 5/3/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 18 5/3/2023 - 5/10/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 19 5/11/2023 - 5/18/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 20 5/19/2023 - 5/26/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 21 5/27/2023 - 6/3/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 22 6/4/2023 - 6/11/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 23 6/12/2023 - 6/19/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 24 6/20/2023 - 6/27/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 25 6/28/2023 - 7/5/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 26 7/5/2023 - 7/12/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 27 7/13/2023 - 7/20/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 28 7/21/2023 - 7/28/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 29 7/29/2023 - 8/5/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 30 8/6/2023 - 8/13/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 31 8/14/2023 - 8/21/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 32 8/22/2023 - 8/29/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 33 8/30/2023 - 9/6/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 34 9/7/2023 - 9/14/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 35 9/15/2023 - 9/22/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 36 9/23/2023 - 9/30/2023
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 37
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 38
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 39
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 40
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 41
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 42
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 43
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 44
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 45
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 46
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 47
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 48
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 49
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 50
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 51
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 52
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 53
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 54
----------------------------------------------------
Week: 55
----------------------------------------------------
```

I am currently not sure what to try at the given moment. I have only tried making additional changes to my function by splitting up the months in to separate else if statements so there wouldn't be so many arguments on one line, but other than that I have not tried anything else, and that is why I am here now. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Thank you ? I'm not sure what I did wrong

Comment: `courseOfLife = (rand() % 350) + 349;` results in a range of 349 to 698. Can you explain why you think it would be different? Consider putting together a [mcve], there's too much missing to really diagnose the issue.

Comment: One thing that would probably be useful would be to run your code in a debugger and step through the code line by line verifying that it is doing what you expect.

Comment: @retired Ninja. I wasn't sure how the range thing worked. I'm not sure what is missing either. I give my entire function to increase by 7 days through the months of the year.

Comment: After the last week printed 9/23 - 9/30 day ends up at 31 and your code doesn't handle that in the `month == 9` block. https://godbolt.org/z/j5z688rj7 Hopefully this gives you some tips on how to debug issues like this.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you so much. This is a tool I will definitely use to run my code from now on. It wasn't something I thought of before hand, and didn't think it needed to be handled. I am still a beginning coder.